# How to fix 'replace' keyword when it is not working in python

Tags: python, replace, strip

I am writing a code that needs to get four individual values, and one of the values has the newline character in addition to an extra apostrophe and bracket like so: 11\n']. I only need the 11 and have been able to strip the '], but I am unable to remove the newline character.

I have tried various different set ups of strip and replace, and both strip and replace are not removing the part.

```
with open('gil200110raw.txt', 'r') as qcfile:
    txt = qcfile.readlines()
    line1 = txt[1:2]
    line2 = txt[2:3]
    line1 = str(line1)
    line2 = str(line2)
    sptline1 = line1.split(' ')
    sptline2 = line2.split(' ')
    totalobs = sptline1[39]
    qccalc1 = sptline2[2] 
    qccalc2 = sptline2[9]
    qccalc3 = sptline2[16]
    qccalc4 = sptline2[22]
    qccalc4 = qccalc4.strip("\n']")
    qccalc4 = qccalc4.replace("\n", "")
```

I did not get an error, but the output of print(qccalc4) is 11\n. I expect the output to be 11.

Comment: is there a literal `'\n'` in the string?

Comment: `"11\n']".strip("\n']").strip("\n")` returns `'11'`...

Comment: yes there is a literal '\n' in the string....

Comment: In my code, it returned 11\n, and I am not sure what really happened.... I am sorry I cannot be more help. Is there a different syntax that I should use???

Comment: If there's a literal `\n` in the string, then you should use `qccalc4.replace("\\n", "")`

Comment: This now works thank you!!!!

Comment: Your `lineX` manipulations are causing you some challenges later on. Rather than slicing your list of strings, only to convert back to a single string with `str`, you probably want `line1 = txt[1]` and `line2 = txt[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use rstrip instead!

```
>>> 'test string\n'.rstrip()
'test string'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match the outputs you're looking for.

From your description, I assume it is all integers, consider the following snippet

```
import re
p = re.compile('[0-9]+')
sample = '11\n\'] dwqed 12 444'
results = p.findall(sample)
```

`results` would now contain the array `['11', '12', '444']`.

`re` is the regex package for python and p is the pattern we would like to find in our text, this pattern `[0-9]+` simply means match one or more characters 0 to 9

you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)